# Why std::optional<bool> uses two bytes?

Tags: c++, memory, stl

If C++ allows `bool` to use any bit, What stops C++ from optimizing `std::optional`to use 1 byte and use two bits for representing `has_value` and `value()`? Sure, we would use a mask, but in modern processors it won't hurt perf.

Comment: "If C++ allows 'bool' to use any bit" since when is that? `sizeof(bool) == 1`. Do you suggest to specialize `std::optional<bool>` to be "special"? we already have one abdomination caused by such line of thinking no need for one more.

Comment: I recommend you make a `dv::optional_bool` that does everything that `std::optional<bool>` does, but with a better memory footprint.

Comment: no, please, not another `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: @idclev463035818, Never mind, my brain died and forgot `optional` returns references.

Answer (score 6):

[This:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*)

> ```
> constexpr const T& operator*() const&;
> constexpr T& operator*() &;
> constexpr T&& operator*() &&;
> ```

Makes what you want impossible. `operator*` needs to return a reference to the held object.

Comment: I don’t see why this would be a problem. Calling `operator*()` on an optional that does not contain a value is undefined behaviour, so as long true and false are represented by 1 and 0 (e.g. by having an `not_has_value` bit) it seems to me like it could work.

Comment: @nemetroid in the OP proposal the `std::optional<bool>` would not contain a `bool` data member, but a byte of raw memory (e.g. `unsigned char`) where certain bits have certain meaning. The standard mandates taht `operator*` returns a reference to the held `bool` object. Since there would not be any `bool` object, you can't create and return such a reference in a meaningful way.